# Как портировать USB протокол для WiFi адаптера из исходных кодов Linux драйвера на Java?

Tags: java, linux, wifi, драйвер

Задача следующая - реализовать протокол взаимодействия между WiFi  свистком и Android устройством по USB-OTG кабелю при этом не получая root прав и не модифицируя ядро, то есть реализовать в виде библиотеки на Java с использованием 
 Android USB API. В частности нужно взаимодействие с адаптерами на чипсете [AR9271](https://github.com/qca/open-ath9k-htc-firmware) (код драйвера под Linux). Я нашел [usb_api.c](https://github.com/qca/open-ath9k-htc-firmware/blob/f43f19cc17ed0f97b292d02274753a486e7088b4/sboot/magpie_1_1/sboot/hif/usb/src/usb_api.c). Но не могу разобраться какие части должны быть реализованы на Java. Пожалуйста, объясните мне или напрвьте хотя бы в каком направлении копать...

P/S то есть аналог [этого](https://github.com/brycethomas/liber80211) только для другого адаптера.

Comment: Почитайте о Проблеме XY https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/709/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-xy

Comment: gbg, Комментарий, состоящий только из ссылки, может быть непонятен для автора вопроса и с меньшей вероятностью поможет ему улучшить вопрос. Используйте ссылку на эту статью как дополнение к вашей аргументации, но не вместо нее.

Comment: Я за попкорном схожу. Но в принципе всё возможно, особенно, если кто-то уже реализовал библиотеку `ieee80211` для Java (неважно, на каком языке библиотека написана, важно, чтобы были биндинги для Java).

Answer (score 1):

Надо для начала определиться, как именно мы хотим портировать код.

1. Мы немного понимаем как это работает. В этом случае читаем код, а еще лучше документацию к чипсету, снова читаем код и ищем в нем только те фрагменты, которые нам нужны. К примеру, вырезаем код инициализации, свои параметры можно вхардкодить, затем вырезаем код тех операций, что нам нужны. Продолжать до тех пор, пока не надоест.
2. Мы вообще не понимаем как это работает. В этом случае можно выучить АПИ обоих платформ. Далее можно или переписать вызовы с одной платформы на другую, или пишем обертку-эмулятор, которая изображает из себя платформу, под которую написан код, а сама на самом деле реализует целевое АПИ через АПИ другой платформы.

Так как исходный код на сишке, то JNI будет наиболее простой вариант, что избавит от переписывания кода на другом языке.

Comment: Документации к чипсету нет, есть только исходники драйверов. API Android  я знаю. Я просто не понимаю что есть что в драйверах под Linux, и соответственно что переносить. На что обратить внимание и тд.

Comment: Тогда остается только второй путь. Изучаем API, который используется в драйвере и реализуем его у себя (или заменяем на свою реализацию).

Comment: по поводу JNI  - это тоже не очень хороший вариант, так как там в драйвере все строится на ioctl-ках, и , кроме того, подразные API версии прийдется билдить и таскать либы с собой в приложении. А я как раз хочу быть как можно более независимым в этом плане, когда USB Android API  - универсален для платформы и  весь код драйвера реализован на Java.

Comment: А кто сказал, что будет легко? JNI же позволяет только заменить АПИ и не переписывать весь код. В сборке десятка либ под разные версии ничего сложного не вижу, человечество изобрело системы сборки с кучей опций на любой вкус и цвет.